# Query params in url does not appears in node url after updating

Tags: 7, nodes, path-aliases

I need to append node path programmatically to make the url look like [the link]?utm_source=Home%20Page&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=AB%20Test&utm_content=Headline A

I'm updating node via node_save()

```
$alias = drupal_get_path_alias('node/' . $node->nid);
$queryA = array(

          'utm_source'=>'Home Page',
          'utm_medium'=>'website',
          'utm_campaign'=>'AB Test',
          'utm_content'=>'HeadlineA'
        );

$node->path = array(
    'alias' => $alias,
    'query' => $queryA,
    'pathauto' => FALSE,
    'absolute' => TRUE);

node_save($node);
```

but unfortunately i'm not getting the desired result. Any thoughts how do i do it. do i need append alias?
dpr information for the node path looks like this

```
Array
(
    [alias] => content/esse-iaceo-lenis
    [query] => Array
        (
            [utm_source] => Home Page
            [utm_medium] => website
            [utm_campaign] => AB Test
            [utm_content] => HeadlineA
        )

    [pathauto] => 
    [absolute] => 1
)
```

I got another solution and have used [conditional views module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_conditional) so that absolutely covered my needs . Drupal power!!!

Comment: See if you have better luck using [path_save()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21path.inc/function/path_save/7.x) within a [Node API Hook](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/group/node_api_hooks/7.x) called after `node_save()` inserts and/or updates the node. I'm not 100% sure, but I think you need to implement these hook(s) in a module; they won't work in a theme..

Comment: i do that in module and path_save () seams limited to me. can i do query in path_save ?

Comment: You are right, `['query']` isn't available in `path_save()`. Could you clarify something please: Are you trying to add those parameters to the URL the user is redirected to after they submit a node edit/add/delete form? Are you trying to add them to the path stored in the database for viewing the node? Or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: As from my questions on title click  the link have to be exp:  [the link]?utm_source=Home%20Page&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=AB%20Test&utm_content=Headline A 
What i do is : trying to append the path with the query and on node_save. I'm adding and debug information shows query is added to the path array. but when i'm hovering on title or on title click i don have it in browsers address bar. so should i append alias ? to have the link with those utm tags for google analytics

Comment: The reason I asked those two questions is: 1) I searched Drupal core's `modules/node` and `modules/path` for the array key `'query'`, and it looked like it was always used for the page that the user is returned to after saving or deleting a node. 2) I wanted to know if it was important to you that the url query parameters are saved to the database, or that you only cared that they are in the links but it doesn't matter how they got there. But now it looks like your final goal is to get campaign data to Analytics. Does it matter how you get the data there, or must it be from query parameters?

Comment: Thanks for the questions . Let me be more clear on what i do. I do A/B test for node titles, changing title  to the visitors and i need to save previous url and add tag to it that's why i turned the pathauto for the node url and i need  tracking tags in a format i mentioned. Do i need that tags in DB i don't think so it needs to be just for a click when visitor clicks on the title or read more button - so that analytics tag should be in link. Do i need this in query ? No it is not to important .

Comment: As i mentioned link should be in the way  [the link]?utm_source=Home%20Page&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=AB%20Test&utm_content=Headline A . I have searched through the internet for solutions the only one i found to append alias with additional query and save it. If i do this after few saves the path alias becomes to long and breaks the web :) . So any thoughts will be helpful.

Comment: @runswithscissors I have looked more and got hook_url_outbound_alter()  that hook to work with url. any ideas how to use it with node?

Comment: You can use `hook_url_outbound_alter()` to alter URLs for just nodes `if ($options['entity_type']=='node')`. The problem is you can't know what asked for the URL, so the params will be added to the node URL in header items, like canonical or og:url, and may harm SEO. I personally would forget about using params and try to use the Analytics javascript API to send the info. If you need to use params, then I would consider implementing `hook_preprocess_node` check `$variables['view_mode']== 'teaser'` (or whatever) and change `$variables['node_url']`. But that may also conflict with something.

Comment: Thanks so much for the support , i solved it in another way. as my nodes are in views blocks i have just rewriting output of the required field with https://www.drupal.org/project/views_conditional module and adding straightly to the url required utm codes  and yes preprocess hook will be the solving as well but at the moment i won't bother about it . Thank you !!!